# subdomain rewriteurl in PHP

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I have set up my domain to point all wildcard subdomains to my webserver. What I would like to do is to perform a rewrite url based on the value that I receive on the wildcardsubdomain.

This is a specific scenario which I am not sure how to over come.

`username.mydomain.com` to rewrite to `mydomain.com/user.php?userid=username`

&

`groupname.mydomain.com` to rewrite to `mydomain.com/group.php?groupid=groupname`

I am storing on my db on a table the types as below.

```
john->userid
technology->groupid
steve->userid
Macleen->userid
Sports->groupid
```

Would this be helpful to acheive this programatically? How can I acheive this using rewriteURL?

> And I would also like to keep the URL's of the page as is till the
>   user navigates to another page from either `user.php` or `group.php`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ file.php?id=%1 [L]
```

You could then place some sort of id check in file.php to find out if it's a username or groupname, would only work if you had unique ids for both combined though as there's no way to seperate random.mydomain.com from random.mydomain.com.

You could then use javscript to format the url:

```
 history.pushState({path: "url"}, "", "http://random.mydomain.com/user");
```

Answer (score 1):

index.php :

```
<?php
if(preg_match('/([a-z]+).mydomain.com/i', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], $matches)){
  $subdomain = $matches[1];
  if(YourModel::isGroupName($subdomain)){
    $_GET['groupid'] = $subdomain;
    require './group.php';
  } else {
    $_GET['userid'] = $subdomain;
    require './user.php';
  }
}
```